# Using filter on angular-tree-component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the angular-tree-component (https://angular2-tree.readme.io/) . I would like to implement the filter functionality but from the documentation it's not really clear to me how to start using the filtering in Angular (4).

If you have

```
<tree-root id="tree" [focused]="true" [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
```

and you want to do filtering by string as on the documentation page:

```
tree.treeModel.filterNodes("text", true);
```

I would like to know how to access the tree-root from my component and then execute the filterNodes().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expose the component as a @ViewChild and access it inside your component.

```
<tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>
```

In your component do:

```
@ViewChild('tree') treeComponent: TreeComponent;
```

And finally, execute the search on the component by calling `filterNodes`:

```
treeComponent.treeModel.filterNodes("text", true);
```

Full example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<div style="text-align:center">
              <br/>
              <input [(ngModel)]="filter">
              <button (click)="filterTree()">Filter</button>
              <tree-root #tree [nodes]="nodes"></tree-root>
            </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('tree') treeComponent: TreeComponent;

  filter = '';

  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  filterTree() {
    this.treeComponent.treeModel.filterNodes(this.filter);
  }
}
```

See more here: [How to invoke methods](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/treemodel)

Comment: Works very well! Thank you very much. Indeed the page for the TreeModel also provides some good information to do this, I did not check this page before.